# Math Topic of the Week

Tags: feature-request

There was recent concern on the [Statistics on upvoting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6668/19341). Maybe one way to push the decreasing rate of votes towards a higher level again, might be something special:

They had the ["Philosophy Topic of the Week"](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/427/1127) over there at [philosophy.stackexchange.com](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/). Why not having something like that, here as well? (Ok, it didn't work that well at philosophy.)

**EDIT** Ok forget about the vote statistics...

What do you think?

Comment: Just so that we know, I looked at the recent voting patterns, and though there was a brief lull in voting earlier in the year, there are more votes now on average than ever before.

Comment: "More votes now on average" --- does that mean more votes per average answer? per average question? per average day? per average voter?

Comment: @Gerry: It means more votes per day on average. We also have more posts per day on average and more very-quickly-closed-posts per day on average, so counting votes per post seems very hard. Perhaps one explanation for an apparent slow-down of votes is that the voting base itself is not perhaps growing as fast as the number of questions/answers, given how many people use the site for a very small number of questions. But that is speculation. All I really know is that there are far more votes per day on average than ever before.

Comment: @mixedmath, thanks. If, just to make up some numbers out of thin air, posts per day are up 50% since January, and votes per day are up only 20%, people will feel that as a decreasing rate of votes. Questions will get fewer votes (on average), answers will get fewer votes (on average).

Comment: @mixedmath it's just been 14 days since Matt asked: "Has there recently been statistically less upvoting than usual?" and Phira answered: "...there has been a recent drop by half a vote per answer in the last two months...".

Comment: @mixedmath, do you think that's enough support for the topic of week?

Answer (score 16):

I'm all in favour of a topic of the week, but I am not sure it will actually increase votes per post.

Answer (score 5):

No, we don't need it.  ${ }$ ${ }$ ${ }$ ${ }$ ${ }$ ${ }$ ${ }$